# Numpy .shape function

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, shapes

I am teaching myself Python, and encountered an issue I am having difficulty circumventing. I am trying to experiment with the .shape function in the Numpy library and am unable to circumvent this message. The source code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
a.shape
```

The error received is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-55-091b86d34e0e> in <module>
      4          [17, 22, 27])
      5 a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
----> 6 a.shape

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Comment: With a list use `len(a)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `import numpy as np`, you need to use `np` in some way, i.e. create a numpy array and use its method [shape](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html#numpy-ndarray-shape):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]) # a now has numpy.array methods and properties    
a.shape
```

Output

```
(9,)
```

Answer (score 1):

.shape is numpy array's property, not Python built-in list's.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
a.shape
```